# No data in email

Tags: php, html, css

I have created my page and have incorporated a form. I believe I have set everything up correctly, however when I receive the email, none of the input data is shown?

jsFiddle attached: https://jsfiddle.net/ebw2d9s5/1/

phpcode:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "Error: You need to Submit the Form!";
}

$to = "admin@hosting-mate.com"; // this is your Email address
$headers = "From:" . $from ;

$name = $_POST['name'];
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$message = $name . " " . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

$subject = "DKS Online Quote Form";
$subject2 = "DKS Electrical and Data";

$response = "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . " for contacting us, we will be in contact with you shortly.";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$response);

header('Location: ../index.php');
// You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
// You cannot use header and echo together. It's one or the other.
?>
```

Here is the test site: http://www.hosting-mate.com/dkselectricalanddata/

EDIT - This is all that shows up in my emails: http://www.hosting-mate.com/dkselectricalanddata/_assets/img.png

Thanks in advance!
 - Jesse

Comment: Your mail will be sent even if the form is not submitted. Check the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` part.

Comment: Hi b0s3, the form is filled in when I click "Send" however nothing appears but the headings for "wrote the following:". What should I be looking at with the    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) ?

Comment: change `echo "Error: You need to Submit the Form!";` to `die("Error: You need to Submit the Form!");`

Comment: PLEASE LOOK AT MY EDIT

Comment: Would it be a problem as my send_form.php is seperate from my index.html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many different things to figure out why my data never came up in my emails, I realized that it was actually the HTML file that was not sending the data properly.

For anyone else that may run into this issue with a data form, dont use:

```
enctype:"text/plain"
```

Instead, use:

```
enctype:"multipart/form-data"
```

This will stop your emails from appearing with just the headings and no input data.

Thank you for everyone that tried helping with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $to = "admin@hosting-mate.com"; // this is your Email address
 $headers = "From:" . $from ;

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $address = $_POST['address'];
 $message = $name . " " . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

 $subject = "DKS Online Quote Form";
 $subject2 = "DKS Electrical and Data";

 $response = "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . " for contacting us, we will be  in contact with you shortly.";

 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 mail($from,$subject2,$response);

 header('Location: ../index.php');
 // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
 // You cannot use header and echo together. It's one or the other.
}else {
 echo "Error: You need to Submit the Form!";
 }
?>
```

Change this in your HTML Code :

```
<input type="submit" class="button" id="Button2" value="SEND" style="position:absolute;left:0%;top:640px;width:100%;height:80px;font-family:font_header;font-size:27px;z-index:20">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" id="Button2" value="SEND"   style="position:absolute;left:0%;top:640px;width:100%;height:80px;font-family:font_header;font-size:27px;z-index:20">
```

Comment: Hi Bipin,
I have tried that however it sends me to the echo "Error"?

Comment: Tried that with still no success

Comment: check the post data by print_r($_POST);die; Is it displaying all form fileds?

Comment: Could you please inform me of where I am to place that code? I am very new to PHP and am trying to wrap my head around things still. Thanks